# Combining Blender textures into 1 piece

Tags: texturing

I'm completely new to designing and blending. I've got a some .blend model I downloaded which contains textures. In 3ds max there's that way to add 1 image texture onto the model and it's automatically assigns it. Question is if it's possible to export all the .blend file textures into 1 image as a whole? If it is and you're willing to explain, please be very much specific what to do since I'm not familiar with almost anything. Thanks!! stay safe.